# How to declare a structure variable globally in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have declared a public structure on top of some module:

```
<Serializable()> Public Structure aSetup
    Dim check As Boolean
    Dim times As Double
    Dim sTimes As Integer
    Dim noone As String
End Structure
```

Before using it in any form or module I have to declare a local variable from this structure.

For example:

```
Dim asT as aSetup
asT.noone = "Nemo"
```

I would like to know if is possible to declare the `asT` variable globally so structure data can be achievable through all files. How and where do I do that, if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put it in a static class - called a `Module` in VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Shared` instance of the structure attached to some class.  Something like:

```
Public Class Settings
    Private Shared Property asTInitialized As Boolean = False
    Private Shared _asT As aSetup
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property asT As aSetup
        Get
            If Not asTInitialized Then
                _asT.noone = "Nemo"
                'other init code

                asTInitialized = True
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Then in other files access it via `Settings.asT`.

Comment: This is very interesting approach!